# Python Eclipse ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, eclipse

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I want to use a python module in Eclipse. However, I get a ModuleNotFoundError all the time. 
Code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import * # Grab MATLAB plotting functions
from control.matlab import *    # MATLAB-like functions

# Parameters defining the system
m = 250.0            # system mass
k = 40.0            # spring constant
b = 60.0            # damping constant

# System matrices
A = [[0, 1.], [-k/m, -b/m]]
B = [[0], [1/m]]
C = [[1., 0]]
sys = ss(A, B, C, 0);
```

Where `ss` is a member of the `control.matlab` module. 
I installed everything properly and the control toolbox also appears in the preferences as a package and in the System Libs list. Still I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\...\control_test\root\nested\control.py", line 5, in <module>
    from control.matlab import *    # MATLAB-like functions
  File "D:\Users\...\control_test\root\nested\control.py", line 5, in <module>
    from control.matlab import *    # MATLAB-like functions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'control.matlab'; 'control' is not a package
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your file structure? Looks like you forgot an `__init__.py` somewhere

Comment: Seems like the package "control" is not in python's path. Plus, the script you run is called `control.py`, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's correct and was also the problem. Didn't realize they couldn't have the same name. Thank you very much guys!